# How to import and compile Android FBReaderJ source code into Eclipse (Windows)?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to import and compile [FBReaderJ](http://www.fbreader.org/FBReaderJ/) on eclipse. I have downloaded the latest source code from their website. Is it necessary to install NDK and cygwin for compiling FBRreaderJ.
If you can suggest me any tutorial OR helpful link.

FYI:

OS – Windows vista 
Eclipse – [Helios 3.6] 
Android OS – 1.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the HowToBuild text file in the root dir, it gives instructions.
It mentions the requirements:

- Android SDK >= 1.6
- Android NDK >= r4b
- Apache Ant >= 1.7.0
- python

And since the NDK requires cygwin 1.7 on Windows, it looks like you'll have some downloading to do.

So yes, you need the NDK, Cygwin, and Python

The text file also gives build instructions:

*EDIT* new instructions:

> To build:
>
> 1. Create 'local.properties' file containing sdk.dir && ndk.dir definitions:  sdk.dir=    ndk.dir= E.g., on my computer 'local.properties'
>      consists of 2 lines:   sdk.dir=/Users/geometer/android-sdk-mac_86
>      ndk.dir=/Users/geometer/android-ndk-r4b
> 2. If you use Linux or MacOS, just run 'ant package' and go to step 3. For debugging  purposes, you might want to run 'ant dbg' for building
>      the package in debug mode, signing  with your debug key (in this case,
>      you can skip step 3).
>
> If you are Windows user   2a. Run ndk-build (a program from Android
>   NDK directory) in your project catalog;
>         This program only runs from Cygwin >= 1.7, please read NDK docs for details.
>         Read and try config cygwin using 'cygwin_installation_and_configuration.pdf'   2b. Run 'ant release'.
>
> 3. Sign your package manually.

Comment: What is and where is createRawResources.py ?!

Comment: Since I posted this answer, they've changed their instructions and have removed any reference to that script.
Check out the updated instructions on their github https://github.com/geometer/FBReaderJ/blob/master/HowToBuild

Answer (score 1):

To make FBReaderJ working you can refer to the following link:
https://github.com/geometer/FBReaderJ/raw/maste/docs/cygwin_installation_and_configuration.pdf
it tells you all about how to download and intstall cygwin.
There is highest possibility of getting error: "NDK command not found". In that case refer to this link:: http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/